# Is AC Dimmer on Vector Board trouble?

Tags: arduino, ac, dimmer

I'm building an AC Dimmer based on this circuit (linked) and am considering using a Vector board instead of making a PCB. Does anyone foresee any issues with this? Particularly regarding 120v channeling through jumpers?

On a previous post @supercat suggested spacing out the 120v area to avoid arcs (which i'll do).

http://wiki.dxarts.washington.edu/groups/general/wiki/4dd69/AC_Dimmer_Circuit.html

Comment: The link is dead as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vector makes many kinds of boards, from pad-per-hole to various styles of holes connected by strips of copper.

In any case, the "creepage" distances between adjacent pads/strips is not all that large, so I would recommend leaving *several* (not just one) unused pads/strips between circuit nodes that have 120VAC across them. And be sure to clean any unused flux/rosin off the board when you're finished soldering.

In a pinch, you might consider using the heat of your iron to delaminate and remove unused strips between high-voltage nodes.

Comment: "consider using the heat of your iron to delaminate and remove unused strips between high-voltage nodes" => good advice.